# Solve a non-linear and nonhomogeneous ODE of the second order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is it possible to solve: $yy''+y'=x$ on term of special functions, or well in a parametric way?
Homogeneous case is immediate:
$$y=\text{constant, and} \,\, x=\int \frac{dy}{\log{y}}+C.$$